# Qual a origem da seguinte expressão : "Janeiro fora cresce uma hora"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, expressões, português-europeu, significado-em-contexto

Qual a origem da seguinte expressão "Janeiro fora cresce uma hora"?

Relacionada com dias maiores.

No hemisfério sul não se deve aplicar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse provérbio constata um facto óbvio: em janeiro os dias vão ficando mais longos. Isto em Portugal, claro. Em grande parte do Brasil a duração do dia não varia muito ao longo do ano, e no sul é o contrário: em janeiro os dias vão ficando mais curtos.

O ditado já aparece em [1885 neste *Archivo dos Açores*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=NV88AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA212&dq=%22Janeiro%20fora%20j%C3%A1%20cresce%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_ouuGke3zAhWDR_EDHRQaAFIQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22Janeiro%20fora%20j%C3%A1%20cresce%22&f=false), o exemplo mais antigo que encontrei:

> O peior era os días serem tão pequenos que não davam para nada mas tambem **Janeiro fora já cresce uma hora**, o verdadeiro era ir desde já cortando alguma madeira para os barrotes e armação, pol-a em casa e levar ao cabo semelhante empresa.
> Archivo dos Açores, Ponta Delgada, 1885

Este [*Metereología popular* de 1896](https://books.google.pt/books?id=A44MAQAAIAAJ&q=%22Janeiro%20fora%20mais%22&dq=%22Janeiro%20fora%20mais%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-69uHku3zAhU5Q_EDHU3FClEQ6AF6BAgCEAI) regista uma variante:

> **Janeiro fora, mais uma hora; e quem bem contar hora e meia há de achar**

Existem provérbios semelhantes em castelhano e catalão ([Calendário romance de refranes, 2003](https://books.google.pt/books?id=rztfifMvKwIC&pg=PA28&dq=%22Janeiro%20fora%20mais%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiN6cXdku3zAhUwA2MBHRiTBtgQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22Janeiro%20fora%20mais%22&f=false)).

Comment: Jacinto, talvez essa seja uma nova pergunta, mas o que significa "fora" nesse caso?

Comment: "Esse provérbio constata um facto óbvio", me assustou, até ler "Isto em Portugal, claro" hahaha. Tenho a mesma dúvida que o stafusa, apesar de agora conseguir imaginar algo devido ao significado.

Comment: @stafusa, interpreto como o mesmo que *afora*; é capaz de haver uma elipse, *por janeiro fora*, compara *pelo mundo fora*. É capaz de valer a pena uma nova pergunta: é capaz de se encontrar noutros casos e ter um interesse mais geral.

Comment: @Rafael, pois, eu hesitei entre o rigor de qualificar logo ao princípio (facto óbvio das latitudes tal e tal) mas optei por maior fluidez. Vê comentário acima também.

Comment: Ok @Jacinto agora vi no Houaiss que "fora" pode significar "afora" e então fica mais claro. Para contribuir com mais uma pergunta ao site, no entanto, [segui tua sugestão](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/9011/2764) e postei como uma nova pergunta. Te aguardo lá. :-)

Comment: Nesse caso fora signifoca "em diante "