# Qual o significado de "fora" em "Janeiro fora cresce uma hora"?

Tags: significado, diferenças-transatlânticas

A questão "[Qual a origem da seguinte expressão "Janeiro fora cresce uma hora"?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/8988/2764)" esclarece o significado desse provérbio, mas a palavra "fora" não parece estar sendo usada com seu significado usual — o do [dicionário](https://dicionario.priberam.org/fora) ou como em "Fora de vista, fora da mente" ou "Por fora, bela viola, por dentro, pão bolorento".

O que exatamente significa "fora" nesse provérbio, e é esse sentido ainda corrente em alguma variedade do português?

Fora de "Em diante"

Comment: Uma vez que Janeiro já terminou, se ganha uma hora mais de luz?

Comment: Nunca ouvi este provérbio. Talvez, dentro de um contexto fique mais fácil identificar o significado. Vi que existe uma versão mais extensa: "janeiro fora, mais uma hora, e quem bem contar, hora e meia há de achar".

Comment: @zewill Eu também não conhecia, não acredito que seja de uso corrente em pt-BR.

Comment: Nem em Portugal. Eu também não conhecia. E cresci numa zona rural, que são mais dadas a estas meteorologias populares

Comment: De qualquer maneira, no Brasil, só se fosse lá bem para o sul, e teria de ser *janeiro fora, mingua uma hora* ou *julho fora, cresce uma hora*.

Answer (score 4):

Eu entendi *janeiro fora* como *pelo janeiro fora*, análogo a *pela noite fora*. Haveria aqui uma elisão do *pelo*, que é até mais comum do que eu pensava (exemplos abaixo). Mais à frente no provérbio há também a elisão de algo como *o dia*. Seria portanto, ***pelo janeiro fora, o dia cresce uma hora*** ou *ao longo de janeiro, o dia cresce uma hora*.

Este uso de *fora* vem em vários dicionários: [Aulete 5](https://www.aulete.com.br/fora), [Michaelis 5](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/fora/), [Infopédia 4](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/fora). Mas a explicação mais completa que encontrei foi no Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (2001):

> **fora¹** […] **4** A seguir a grupo nominal regido pela preposição *por*, usa-se com o sentido de extensão, no espaço ou no tempo ≈ Ao longo de, Através de. *Teve muitos problemas pela vida fora*. «[…] *ficava a conversar pela noite fora*» […] «[…] *foram andando pela estrada fora*» […]

A princípio pensei que a elisão do *por* ou *pelo* em *janeiro fora* fosse licença poética, mas se é há muito boa gente a servir-se dela. Exemplos, incluindo do século XIX, uma vez que o provérbio já existia então:

> [Gabriel Pedro] **relatava-me noite fora** as lutas heroicas em que participara.
> [Zita Seabra, *Foi assim*, 2007](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ddf7MNIYs2EC&pg=PT56&dq=%22noite%20fora%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-0Ja1gvXzAhUpgP0HHdKaAvEQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=%22noite%20fora%22&f=false)
>
> […] montou a cavallo e **seguiu estrada fora**, sem dizer para onde ia
> [Júlia Lopes de Almeida, *A família Medeiros*, 1894](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Xa5OAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA57&dq=%22estrada%20fora%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0rv3qhPXzAhUqRPEDHa25DawQ6AF6BAgPEAI#v=onepage&q=%22estrada%20fora%22&f=false)
>
> Trepando-se a um banco de ferro, a fim de, alongando a vista, **estrada fora**, enxergar a vinda do pae, Antonita […] desviou prestimosa attenção para uma lanranjeira […]
> [A Illustração, 1887](https://books.google.pt/books?id=JZdRAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA346&dq=%22estrada%20fora%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0rv3qhPXzAhUqRPEDHa25DawQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=%22estrada%20fora%22&f=false)
>
> Na quadra azul da mocidade, a gente
> Parte rindo e cantado, **estrada fora**
> [Gonçalves Crespo, *Nocturnos*, 1888](https://books.google.pt/books?id=pDMuAAAAYAAJ&pg=PR15&dq=%22estrada%20fora%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0rv3qhPXzAhUqRPEDHa25DawQ6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=%22estrada%20fora%22&f=false)

Comment: Curioso! Parece-me que "fora" utilizado assim, como advérbio, seja mais natural como "afora". "Pela noite afora". Essa expressão "estrada fora" soa como linguagem arcaica.

Comment: @zewill, bem, o provérbio está atestado já em 1885 (vê a pergunta sobre a origem dele, lincado na pergunta). Mas eu tendo a dizer *estrada fora* e não *estrada afora*; é verdade que eu já começo a ser um nadinha arcaico :) Mas o Google (geral e Books) dá montes de *estrada fora* recentes. Onde eu uso *afora* é no *e por aí afora*.

Comment: Boa! Já estou bem arcaico também :D

Answer (score 3):

Para mim, Janeiro fora, quer dizer quando já não é janeiro. Ou seja, um vocativo: Janeiro fora! Saia daqui. :)

Que nem: Roberto, fora! Preciso trabalhar.

Do Priberam:

**Expressão usada para afastar ou mandar embora. = ALA,**

"fora", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/fora [consultado em 30-10-2021].

[É curioso esse ala, também existe em español com um sentido ligeiramente diferente. :)]

Answer (score 1):

O provérbio
**Janeiro fora, mais uma hora** é usado para indicar "Janeiro terminado, (os dias duram) mais uma hora".

Também é habitual: **Janeiro fora, mais uma hora e quem bem contar hora e meia há-de achar**.

Naturalmente só funciona no hemisfério Norte...

Embora as explicações anteriores façam sentido, sempre interpretei este "fora" como semelhante ao "patrão fora, dias santo na loja" ou seja:
"quando o padrão deixa a loja, sai da loja, deixa de estar presente", ...

Neste caso **quando o janeiro nos deixa** = quando Janeiro termina = Janeiro terminado, ...

Já agora, no caso concreto de Braga o aumento é cerca de 54 minutos (ou seja o provérbio
é optimista)